# weak convergence and continuity

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $F:X \rightarrow X'$, $X'$ being the dual space of the normed linear space $X$, is a continuous map. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$ which converges weakly to $x$ in $X$. Can I conclude that $F(x_n)\rightarrow F(x)$ in $X'$?. I reckon it may not converge to $F(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\ell_2$. Let also $F$ be the identity map (it is continuous, because $\ell_2'=\ell_2$) and $x_n$ form the canonical basis.

We know that $x_n\rightharpoonup 0$ (i.e. weakly) in $\ell_2$. However, $F(x_n)=x_n$ does not converge in $\ell_2'$ (even though it converges in $w-\ast$ topology).

Comment: Thanks @ TZakrevskiy...For the basis $\{e_1=(1,0,0,...), e_2=(0,1,0,...),...,e_i=(0,0,...,0,0,1,0,0...,),...\}$, $<e_i,x>=x_i$ for an $x\in l^{2}$. I am sorry but I couldn't figure out why is $x_n$ converginng weakly to $0$. Pardon me for the naivety if any.

Comment: @Alexander, in fact, my $x_n$ correspond to your $e_n$. For a fixed $y\in\ell_2$ we can say that $(y,e_n)=y_n$; in addition, $\sum_j |y_j|^2<+\infty$, hence necessarily $y_n\to 0$ and therefore $(y,e_n)\to 0$, which implies that the sequence of vectors $e_n$ converge weakly to zero.

Comment: Ok...thanks a lot.